# Android and Token Authentication

Tags: android, authorization, token

I am using [Fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel) to connect to a web service that require a token authorization. I set the authorization header but server return **401**, Cannot see where's the problem.

`api.httpPut().header(mapOf("Authorization" to "Bearer $tokenId")).responseString { request, response, result -> }`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone got the same problem, I need to save cookie from login response, and send it again in next requests with the authorization header.

I hope this save someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Is Apache on the server? You can try to add .htacess
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

Comment: I don't have access to server, and I access same server from iOS and it works.